# How to stop the user editing the country code in a html page using ngx-international-phone-number in angular 6

Tags: html, css, angular6

Can we stop the user editing the country code in ngx-international-phone-number using angular 6  
imported ngx-international-phone-number in appmodule.ts

Answer (score 2):

you can make this non editable. I have taken the example of Singapore country code. I have used **keydown event**. and I am checking the last position of country code.so if I have country code **+65**  then I am considering **selectionStart** greater than equal to 3.

> My Html Code

```
<form name="sample-form" (ngSubmit)="submit(f)" #f="ngForm">
    <international-phone-number ngModel (keydown)="testInput($event)" name="phone_number" placeholder="Enter phone number" [maxlength]="20" [defaultCountry]="'sg'" [required]="true" #phoneNumber="ngModel" name="phone_number" [allowedCountries]="['sg']"></international-phone-number>

     <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !phoneNumber.valid" class="help-block">Phone number is required and should be valid</div>
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
```

> *and my .ts file code is as below.*

```
    testInput(event) 
{
  if (!(event.target.selectionStart >= 3) || (event.target.selectionStart < 4 && event.key === 'Backspace')) 
  {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

> code to get the value on form submit.

```
    submit(f: NgForm) {
  console.log(f.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best and simplest way you can stop a user editing an input is by adding the `disabled` attribute to the input.

For example `<input type="text" name="countrycode" disabled>`>

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: <international-phone-number [(ngModel)]="loginData.phone"  [(ngModel)]="loginData.countrycode"  placeholder="Enter phone number" [maxlength]="20" [defaultCountry]="'in'" [required]="false"  #phone_number="ngModel" name="phone_number"></international-phone-number>

Comment: Imported this library, it itself creates a input box and binds the country code and phone number in a single input box. So we cannot give a disabled attribute to that