# ngx-international-phone-number remove the country code or make as non editable

Tags: angular

> I imported ngx-international-phone-number plugin to my project. and
>   its working fine. But I want to customize the plugin. I want disable
>   country code or remove country code.Also please suggest me some another plugin
>   without country code or with disabled county code.

[link to import ngx-international-phone-number package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-international-phone-number)

[image]

> I want to disable country code i.e +91. or remove.

Comment: Were you able to get solution for this? @Sitesh

Comment: Yes, I was. Please refer to my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52623753/how-to-stop-the-user-editing-the-country-code-in-a-html-page-using-ngx-internati/58953300#58953300

Comment: Is there anyway to add a space after the country code display. Right now, when i type a mobile number, it doesnt leave any space before the mobile number